# When was this vulnerability fixed in Debian? (CVE-2012-2088 affecting libtiff4)

Tags: debian, security

I have Debian Squeeze installed on my one of my workstation. On my Ubuntu 10.04 workstation there have been two security updates to the libtiff4 package in the last couple of weeks, addressing the [CVE-2012-2088](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-2088) vulnerability, but none to libtiff4 on the Debian installation.

Is the libtiff4 package installed on my Debian system [3.9.4-5+squeeze4] vulnerable? What update fixes it?

More generally, how can I find out whether and when a vulnerability is fixed in Debian?

Comment: This is way too localized but have a look at http://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2012-2088 - so yes the version in squeeze is vulnerable

Comment: Check out [this page](http://www.debian.org/security/) and make sure to subscribe to the debian-security-announce mailing list.